# What does SET @Var = SELECT(...) result in when a row is not found?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my stored procedure, I have the following code:

```
@tn nvarchar(256)

[...]

DECLARE @Var1 int;

SET @Var1 = (SELECT tid FROM t1 WHERE tn = @tn);

IF @Var1 IS NULL
    BEGIN
        --- do something
    END
```

Am I correct to assume that @Var1 will be set to NULL if there are no record is found by the SELECT statement?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

The reason why I'm posting the question is that I've run into a case when the record was not present but @Var1 was not NULL (i.e. the code between BEGIN/END did not execute).

Comment: Yes, it should be null with no rows present

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT(tid FROM t1 WHERE tn = @tn)` result in an error?

Comment: @Morpheus: It was my typo in the pseudo-code.  Sorry. The actual code in the stored proc  is correct.

Comment: I think it would be easier to check if the int is greater than 0?

Comment: In the "real" code which exhibits the problem (which is surely what you should be asking about), was this code inside some form of *loop*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: no, there is no loop in the stored proc.

Comment: Try to distill your problematic situation down into a [mcve] then please. Don't ask about code in isolation that a) doesn't compile and b) doesn't exhibit the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

That code, as it is, won't work, try:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (ID int);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (ID)
VALUES(1),(3);
GO
DECLARE @V int;

SET @V = SELECT (ID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE ID = 3);

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
```

You'll get the errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

The syntax should be:

```
SET @V = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE ID = 3);
```

You can then easily find out your answer:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (ID int);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (ID)
VALUES(1),(3);
GO
DECLARE @V int;

SET @V = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE ID = 2);

SELECT @V; --Returns NULL

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
```

You could even do a statement before it, the result would be the same, for example:

```
DECLARE @V int;

SET @V = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE ID = 3);
SET @V = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE ID = 2);

SELECT @V;
```

Will still return NULL, as the second expression returns NULL.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the bracket in the wrong place was just a typo. However, I always thought that what you said about the second expression was true.  The problem is that I cannot easily replicate the problem.  The 'IF @Var1 IS NULL'  works as expected for me in most cases.  Today was the first time that it did not work 3 times in a row and I started to have some doubts.